# How to change for loop with certain values

Tags: java

I am new to java. I need help with a basic problem. How do I change the for loop limits when a certain condition is met?

For example:

```
x = 0;
y = 100,
z = 20;

for (w=x ; w<=y; w+=z)
{
    System.out.println("this is wat i needed");

    if (w==60)  
        // from here onwards i want to change z value to 4
}
```

Comment: Apparently, you're _so_ new to Java that you can't tell it's a totally different language to Javascript :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int w=x;w<=y;z=(w==60)?4:z,w+=z){
             System.out.println("this is wat i needed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (w==60)  
{
    z = 4; //Simple assignment
}
```

Your code is littered with syntax errors, I made the assumption that they are not present in your actual code.

Also Java and JavaScript are two totally different things.

Answer (score 0):

Just update it

```
x =0;
y=100,
z=20;
for (w=x ; w<=y; w+=z;
{
    System.out.println("this is wat i needed");

    if (w==60)  
        z = 4;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether for loop ends with semi-colon ( ; ) or not.

And for changing the value simply assign `z=4` in the if block !